# Send and receive data from Arduino

Tags: c#, arduino

So I am trying to develop a console application which is able to send and receive automatically data from an Arduino through serial port. Basically this application will be executed as a task scheduler.

Daily, at a certain time the application execute a command to close a door. To do that I will send something like this `comport.Write("y")` and the Arduino will understand that this command will close the door but it will just be closed if the Arduino send to me an ascii command.

I wanna create an if condition which tells something like it:

"If the command sent to the arduino were read then it will response something and I will open the door. If not it will do nothing because the door is already closed."

This is the code I already have:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BackgroundWorker work = new BackgroundWorker();
        work.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(work_DoWork);
        work.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(work_ProgressChanged);
        work.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        work.RunWorkerAsync();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void work_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ProgressPercentage);
    }

    static void work_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker work = sender as BackgroundWorker;
        int grams = -1;
        SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
        port.Open();
        while (true)
        {
            string buff = port.ReadLine();
            int value;
            if (int.TryParse(buff, out value) && value != grams)
            {
                grams = value;
                work.ReportProgress(grams);
            }
        }
    }
```

I wanna use something like this to read what the arduino sent to me and it will continue if the command is correct.

Instead if this int variables I want string variables

Could you guys help me?

Comment: [this](http://playground.arduino.cc/Csharp/SerialCommsCSharp) example from arduino playground should be able to help you to do a char handshake between arduino and C#. They are sending a request to the arduino and the arduino is replying back.

Comment: It was an nice help I will work on it @Josh

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can use [solidsoils4Arduino](https://github.com/SolidSoils/Arduino) to send and receive ASCII commands. Do you have any working code already? how is the arduino detecting if the door is closed?